# logrotate files older than x hours

Tags: linux, bash, cron, crontab, logrotate

What's wrong with this rotate.conf?

Goal is to delete only files older than four hours

```
path/to/tokens/*.tkn {
    nosharedscripts
    prerotate
       if test `stat --format=%Y $1` -le $(( `date +%s` - 14400 ));
       then exit $?;
       fi;'
    endscript
    rotate 0
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You stated your goal is to delete files older than four hours. Using bash 4.3.46 (Ubuntu 16.04) and find 4.7.0 I was able to use a find command with a decimal mtime:

```
find /path/to/tokens/ -name "*.tkn" -mtime 0.1666666
```

Just convert 4/24 to decimal and there you go. You can put that in a script and perhaps pipe-rm or do a `-exec rm {} \;` as desired.

It doesn't use logrotate, but it achieves the goal of deleting the files older than (4/24) days.

#### Edit: bonus round

Apparently there's a `-mmin` option. Try this on for size:

```
find /path/to/tokens/ -name "*.tkn" -mmin +240 -exec rm {} \;
```